# Angular - When to handle errors in Observable's subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

I have found myself working with code from themes written in latest Angular versions and searching the web, and I have found that the most part of devs don't handle the `subscription` error.

My question is: **When do I have to handle the error in an `Observable` subscription?**

Without error handling:

```
    this.myService.observable$.subscribe(
        (data) => {
            // do stuff with data
        }
    );
```

With error handling:

```
    this.myService.observable$.subscribe(
        (data) => {
            // do stuff with data
        },
        err => {
            // do stuff with error
        }
    );
```

I mostly find the first version, but...

Isn't an issue not to handle the errors of a subscription?

Doesn't this make the code less solid, testable and more prone to fail?

Comment: If you want to handle the error and to do some action on error is good practice to have the error Cb set.

Comment: @YordanNikolov Yes, I do have Cb set on my observables, or at least most part of them. But my question was more about Good practices and why respectful developers seem that 'don't follow' them. Maybe there is a different handling that I don't know yet. Maybe it's getting handled in the Observable delcaration directly (like Http requests, for example)

Comment: For me it's always good practice to handle all errors to inform the users, to send those errors to the backend and track it. The other best practice which come up on my mind is, to have separate function handler (function statment) instead of IIF.

Comment: @YordanNikolov 100% with you. That's why I made the question, why not handling these errors. Maybe there was a reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why is error handling important [click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/368190/5868331)

Now Lets see Why error handling is necessary in Observables..

**Example:**

```
this.service.send(this.shareData).subscribe(() => {

      // Here you are sure that the send has shared the data sucessFully

    }, (error) => {

      /* Now If you want to handle errors Like Front End Errors and Log this
         In your backEnd DB So solve it and fix it */

      /* Example below check error type is It from frontEnd and log error through Api */

      if(error.type !== 'API') {
        this.logService.log({
          Level: 2,
          Message: 'Failed to setFromDB',
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: I understand. I know why we should handle errors, but that's why I don't understand very well why in most cases devs don't handle Observable subscription's errors. Is it only related to those subscriptions that directly interact with users?

Comment: Which dev You mean `Angular dev team` or the `dev who use angular`

Comment: let's say community devs. All the examples and themes that I layed my eyes on are absent of subscription's error handling *(at an 80%)*. There must be a reason for this.

Comment: Hmmm. I think so a good developer will handle error if he is creates some function. And solution for your question is angular has provided the feature to handle observable error. Its depends on you to whether to use this feature or not.. If your Function requires to handle the error You should log...

Comment: And according to me for subscribers like user activities you should log the errors as user is the key who uses our service provided. According to users only 0.5% log the errors if they are using your service and others just you know what they do..

Comment: Yep, I was looking a way of explaining **Why devs in general don't handle errors in subscriptions**. And I have received useful information of *Why we should handle errors* or *How to handle errors*, but these things I already knew, although all of you provided useful info. But maybe you were the only ony to actually try to answer the actual question.
The core reasoning here I believe is **depends on what this subscriptions is used for**. If it's internal subscription usage, then error handling is not needed, because if it has an error means that the App don't work and the test fails...

Answer (score 1):

It's good practices to handle error to give users feedback or fall back to a default behavior.

For instance if you try to contact REST service and communication occurred then you might want to inform the user about connectivity problem or load cached data.

Or if the REST service return an error. For example your application is a booking app and user is doing an order but once he submit the order there is no more item in stock. The REST service return and error and you should display to the user that there is no more items.

Furthermore in the angular style guide:

> The details of data management, such as headers, HTTP methods, caching, error handling, and retry logic, are irrelevant to components and other data consumers.

This means that you should return from your service meaningful messages.

Comment: Ok, so is just a personal consideration? Like, only for informing users that *'this broke because of this reason'*. I don't know why this doesn't convince me, I mean, we should always communicate the outcome of the actions to the user, but not handling errors in code is something weird.

Comment: I think that the error is handled in the Observable construction, and therefore, code wise, the error is handled there. Then in the subscription we just handle the feedback to the final user.

Comment: Yes, error is an outcome indeed. But not handling it means 1 day your App breaks and you don't even know why if all your code is full of subscriptions without error handling...

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying need to handle error. Don't let your code crash !

Comment: Yes! So, in your opinion, **ALL** subscriptions should handle errors. Even those subscriptions that are not directly involved with user interactions, for example: Shared service between components in Angular.

Comment: there are rare case that's true. Only case is if your service save and load data in memory it's "safe" to avoid error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your question, but here's how to handle errors inside subscribe on Angular 16:

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe(
 {
   next: (data) => 
   {
     //do something
   },
   error: (error) =>
   {
     //handle error
   }
 }
);
```